# R web scraping >1000 pages, times out

Tags: r, web-scraping

I have the following code to scrape job reviews.

```
reviewDate <- lapply(paste0('https://www.glassdoor.com/Interview/Sears-Interview-Questions-E37984_P', 1:1100, '.htm', sep=''),
                    function(url){
                        url %>% read_html() %>% 
                            html_nodes(".date") %>% 
                            html_text()
                    })
```

This code works if I only have a few hundred pages (I could run 1:280), but I have two problems:
1) it seems to duplicate everything so that I have 2 of every piece of info, and
2) when I run it for all 1100 pages, I get the following error, which stops the loop:

```
Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : HTTP error 504.
```

I read about adding Sys.sleep() to the code, but I'm not sure where it goes in the code to make it work properly. I'm also wondering if there is another or better fix?

Finally, I have more than one node. Can I add them all into one function and align everything into a data frame? The following code did not work for me, as it returns a list of 2, but each is character(0). (I ran just 1:2 for a quick trial.)

```
reviewDate <- lapply(paste0('https://www.glassdoor.com/Interview/Sears-Interview-Questions-E37984_P', 1:2, '.htm', sep=''),
                    function(url){
                        url %>% read_html() %>% 
                            html_nodes(".date") %>% 
                            html_nodes(".summary") %>% 
                            html_nodes(".authorJobTitle") %>% 
                            html_nodes(".pros") %>% 
                            html_nodes(".cons") %>% 
                            html_nodes(".adviceMgmt") %>% 
                            html_text()
                    })
```

Answer (score 0):

`Sys.sleep` is only there to make the loop pause on every iteration. So it goes anywhere in the loop. Here, we can place it to the beginning so it doesn't interfere with the output since you don't use the `return` statement to explicitly return something from that function

```r
reviewDate <- lapply(paste0('https://www.glassdoor.com/Interview/Sears-Interview-Questions-E37984_P', 1:1100, '.htm', sep=''),
                    function(url){
                        Sys.sleep(.1)
                        url %>% read_html() %>% 
                            html_nodes(".date") %>% 
                            html_text()
                    })
```

Note that this doesn't guarantee that you won't get timeout errors. Spamming could cause errors like this but they can also happen for reasons outside your control. Ideally, you'll want to escape or insist on attempting to get the data you want. `tryCatch` is there so your programs won't immediately stop at the first sign of trouble. Here's one approach

```r
getData = function(url){
    Sys.sleep(.1)
    tryCatch({
        url %>% read_html() %>% 
            html_nodes(".date") %>% 
            html_text()
    }, error = function(e){
        NULL
    })

}

n = 1100
scrapedData = vector(length = n,mode = 'list')
while(TRUE){
    indexes = which(sapply(scrapedData,is.null))
    for (i in indexes){
        scrapedData[[i]] = getData(paste0('https://www.glassdoor.com/Interview/Sears-Interview-Questions-E37984_P', i, '.htm'))
    }
    if(!any(sapply(scrapedData,is.null))){
        break
    }
}
```

Here after I am done with a round of requests, I go back and ask for anything I have missed. `tryCatch` ensures that the execution will not be stopped. Note that if you have links that are really bad, this will run forever so you might want to have a limit on the number of times it can run.

For your second, I don't know why you think your approach should work but it suggests a fundamental misunderstanding of either the pipes or the `html_nodes` function. When you pipe the output of `html_nodes(".date")` into `html_nodes(".summary")`, the object no longer has the `summary` section. You isolated the `date` with the previous command so you will get nothing. Those need to be called separately and assigned to different variables

All you need to do is to make sure the function returns an array that can be later merged into a data frame.

Like

```r
getData = function(url){
    Sys.sleep(.1)
    tryCatch({
        html = url %>% read_html()
        date =html %>% 
            html_nodes(".date") %>% 
            html_text()
        summary = html %>% 
            html_nodes('.summary') %>%
             html_text
        return(list(date,summary))
    }, error = function(e){
        NULL
    })

}
```

Note that here I am returning a list as the number of objects read doesn't seem to match and exact way to make them match is outside the scope of the question. You need to look into the page and get better selectors to scrape what you want.

Comment: Thank you. For the tryCatch examples, you removed the pasted url code and start with getData =.Do I need to put the url if using the getData = before function? Also, once the code is run, I don't see a place where it is saving the data to. getData is listed in the GUI as a function, and scrapedData is a list of 0. Should the data be going into scrapedData?

Comment: Trycatch example only shows changes to the function `getData`

Comment: The for loop places the data into scrapedData using the output of the function

Comment: Let's start form the very beginning. Are you familiar with defining functions?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have only done a function like this once before and it was given to me, not written by me, so I am not terribly familiar with them. I'm familiar with basic for loops, if/else statements. From what I understand in your second code example, the 'while' statement is scraping the data and using the previously defined getData function to look for each i (each element of each review) based on the pasted url and putting the data into scrapedData; is any of that correct?

Comment: I just ran the exact code you provided in the second example and it is working for me. I think I messed something up when using the third example to add multiple nodes in addition to .date and .summary.

Comment: Your interpretation is correct. `while (TRUE)` will run forever unless interrupted by `break`. Here `break` is reached once there are no `NULL`s left in the output. The output list is initially entirely `NULL`. The `for` loop within `while` iterates over every element that is `NULL` and tries to fill them. After iterating over everything, the `if` checks to see if there are any `NULL`s left (timeout errors). If there are `NULL`s left, the code is repeated. If the list is fully filled you `break`

Comment: I have a follow-up concern with this process. The code works, and I can pull all of the variables/nodes...usually. After scraping 1879 reviews from 188 pages for a different company, I see that that for some pages, data is missing for ALL reviews on that page for half the variables. Always the same variables (e.g., I have dates and summary but not the pros/cons/advice sections, and there IS data on those pages for those variables). But it works to pull all data for other pages. Is this something with the connection, and is this a common issue that can be worked out?